# jcarousel.jcarousel('visible') delivers wrong number of items

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I use the jcarousel plugin in my project. I use the following function to actualize the pagination of the product slider

```
actualizePagination: function(element) {
    var jcarousel = element.find('.jcarousel');
    var visibleItems = jcarousel.jcarousel('visible').length;
}
```

When I load the page with the product slider the first time, `visibleItems` shows a value of 5 (wrong). Now when I do any event on the productslider, for example resize the browser or click on the jcarosel control, `visibleItems`becomes 6, which is correct. How are jcarosel elements getting set as "visible" in the plugin? is it an update bug?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related in jcarousel v0.3.4. I was getting an incorrect number of pagination items on the first load. Then it fixed itself when I resized browser window. The new window size didn't have to affect the layout of the page but likely triggered an event listener. Then jcarousel get the pagination right. My code was run on document ready.

I then triggered window resize event and it fixed the problem.

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

I tried delaying jcarousel activation and this worked too so I'm sticking to this solution.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            activateCarousel();
        }, 300);

function activateCarousel() {    
      $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

      $('.jcarousel-pagination')
         .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
             $(this).addClass('active');
         })
         .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
             $(this).removeClass('active');
         })
         .jcarouselPagination();
}
```